# What does this phrase mean: "Trying to use Stream to replace ChangeNotifier is outside of the scope of this class."

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

From this https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html
What did the author mean?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR: I think what the author means is that how to refactor from `ChangeNotifier` to `Stream` is not in the scope.

---

`StreamProvider` doesn't rebuild the UI after state change, however, it listens to then Stream change and once the Stream changes, it will rebuild UI.

With that said, `ChangeNotifier` is also used as a mixin to rebuild the UI when data change (with `ChangeNotifierProvider` IIRC), in this sense, using `Stream` is equivalent tousing `ChangeNotifier` and calling `notifyListeners()` after state change.